# local MySQLconnectivity without network access (without mentioning port)

Tags: mysql, database

I want to access Local MySQL files in a similar way it can be accessed using SmallSQL.
Eg.

```
    String driver = "smallsql.server.SSDriver"; 
    String url = "jdbc:smallsql:C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SQuirreL\\db";

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    System.out.println("Connected to smallSQL database");
```

As you can see, i can move my db folder anywhere on my local machine and all i have to do is to mention the path of db folder to connect with it. Similar implementation in mysql, looks like:

```
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF8&user=root&password=#$%^";);
        System.out.println("Connected to MySQL database");
    }
```

So I want to know is there a similar way to do something with MySQL databases, as we can do with SmallSQL, which are stored in $path_to_myql/mysql/data/db ?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL clients don't interact directly with the data storage files: they  have to *connect* to the MySQL server which does that for them (and, in so doing, can handle concurrent connections from multiple clients).  You can however connect to local servers through IPC mechanisms such as [named pipes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/connecting.html#option_general_pipe) (Windows) or [sockets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/connecting.html#option_general_socket) (*NIX) instead of making a TCP connection to a loopback address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting.html), local socket connection is only available on Unix systems (not on Windows).

More importantly, though, you have to realize that SmallSQL is very similar to SQLite because its whole database engine is simply a library linked by your process, and that's why you can open and access database directly on disk.

MySQL, on other hand, runs fully dedicated server daemon, which serves multiple clients and has full control over its internal database files. It can be running on the same physical machine or on remote host, and you cannot tell it where your data files are.

Long story short - you should live with it. MySQL is more complicated, but also works much faster than SmallSQL or SQLite.

Comment: You can, however, use a [named pipe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/connecting.html#option_general_pipe) (which is the closest thing Windows has to a *NIX socket).

Comment: However, I have not seen any software that support this connection type on Windows. Everybody requires network, even for localhost

Comment: Errrr... per my link above, the mysql command-line client supports connecting over a named pipe.

Comment: I see. But *The server must be started with the --enable-named-pipe option to enable named-pipe connections* seems like asking too much. Oh well.